# Eloquent select statement based on a condition in another table

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-4

I have an laravel eloquent select statement which looks like this:

> $test = Test::with(['a.b.companies']) .. and so on

Now, I want to return results for this query based on some company names in companies table.

I tried to write a where clause with various trial and errors but it doesn't work. I am new to laravel and mysql. Any help in the right direction will be good. thanks.

Comment: Post your code please.

Answer (score 0):

You may use `where`, for more reference  : - [Eloquent ORM](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#basic-usage)

```
$test = Test::where('company_name1', '=', $company_name1)->orWhere('company_name2', '=', $company_name2)->get();
```